# Force Travis to build a specific pull request or commit SHA that it missed

Tags: github, travis-ci

Is there a way to tell [travis](http://travis-ci.org) to build a specific SHA or the HEAD of a pull request that it might have previously missed (ie if the webhook failed to fire or get picked up by travis)?

I could push a new commit to that pull request, but a method that doesn't involve changing the branch would be better, either via the travis UI, or travis' or github's APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a feature request open for this: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/895
But for the time being, there's no way to do this.

Comment: The issue's been closed but a comment at the bottom points to this feature: [Triggering builds through the API](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/)

Answer (score 17):

What I've found works is to close the PR in GitHub, then immediately re-open it. That should re-trigger the hook.

Answer (score 1):

Also found that if you own the repository, you can mark the pull-request as closed then mark it as open and you will trigger a new build.